# pip install -e gets "ERROR: can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available " after the code changed?

Tags: python, pip

I have downloaded a python package (**betterproto** exactly) and made minor changes to it, but when I want to install the package (with `pip3 install -e .`) in order to see whether the changes works correctly or not, I got the error shown below:

```
  Running setup.py develop for betterproto
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [1 lines of output]
        ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  WARNING: No metadata found in /root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
  Rolling back uninstall of betterproto
  Moving to /root/myvenv/bin/protoc-gen-python_betterproto
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-lt7zzexf/protoc-gen-python_betterproto
  Moving to /root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/betterproto-2.0.0b3.dist-info/
   from /root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~etterproto-2.0.0b3.dist-info
  Moving to /root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/betterproto/
   from /root/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~etterproto
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
    ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
    [end of output]
```

I don't know where the *build environment* is, but I had installed `setuptools` in my venv before.

The reason I used `pip install -e .` is that when I use `pip install .` or `python3 setup.py install` , the changes to the code are being ignored. for example if you delete some lines of the code, it will be installed like before.

How can I install the package so that I see the result of my changes?

Comment: You mention `pip install` and `python3 setup.py install`, suggesting `pip` is actually `pip3`. And the subprocess, going by the output, uses `python setup.py develop`, which indicates *another* Python version (that may not have setuptools (Python 2?)). So it appears to be a mix up of various different Python and pip versions. Are you using a proper virtual environment or something like that?

Comment: I used `python3.8 -m venv myenv` command to create my venv.
and by using `pip3 install -e . ` the error had some minor changes and I edited it in my question.

Comment: Just to double check: you activated your v-env as well?

Comment: `/root/myvenv/`: are you developing as root user??

Comment: Yes, I have activated my v-env with `source myvenv/bin/activate` command, and yes, I am developing as root user.

Comment: I had the same error trying to install platformio's cli tooling, upgrading to the latest python3 with asdf fixed it for me
https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core-installer/issues/2878